# Auto get phone number when leaving comments on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, comments

I have been through a quite interesting experience with Facebook. Specificly, I see a post of one software company on timeline with the kinda content "leave comment below and we will send you your phone number". In this case, my phone number is completely hidden and no one can see it except for me.

I tested it out and left a random comment. Surprisingly, they sent exactly my phone number. How can they do that? Can anybody explain for me?[Exact phone number??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W97xc.png)

Comment: We should accept to share our personal info, i have no idea how they do this but this is just an example of how private is our personal data...

Comment: That’s probably not a normal post, but an ad. In lead ads there are some possibilities to embed interactive functionality AFAIK, such as a newsletter sign-up form. This is probably something similar.